# Section .bss of Assembly code

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am studying the book: Assembly Language Step By Step - Jeff Duntemann

Here is an example from this book:

```
Section .bss
    BUFFLEN equ 1024
    Buff: resb BUFFLEN
```

In the book .bss is explained as the **uninitialised data** portion of the code. However variable BUFFLEN is indeed initialised, isn't it? What is it that I am missing?

What is the meaning of initialised data in the context of Assembly?

Comment: It is not a variable, just a symbol.  Buff is a variable, it is not initialized.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean it is just a symbol? Value 1024 for is assigned to BUFFLEN, isn't it? And I can access it from anywhere in the code?

Comment: It's just an other name for the constant 1024, not a variable. It has no storage and no location.

Comment: When you write BUFFLEN in your code, NASM will use 1024 instead. Thus `Buff: resb 1024` is what actually is written in your code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*BUFFLEN* will be a compile-time symbol with the said value of 1024. It will only temporarily be stored by NASM in its internal tables while compiling. It will nowhere be stored in the executable.

The section *.BSS* will not be stored in the executable as oppossed to the section *.DATA*
So initialised data in the context of Assembly is data that is present in the executable. It does not depend on the actual value of such data.